# JavaFX8: Hide/Remove vertical scrollbar in TableView

Tags: javafx-8

I would like to hide or remove vertical scrollbar in my TableView. I would like to menage scroll with my own PgUp/PgDown buttons.

Buttons work fine with below code, but the verticalScrollBar ruin the desired aspect. How can I hide/remove it?

```
    btnPgDown.setOnAction(e -> {
        if (table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() == -1) {
            table.getSelectionModel().select(0);
        }
        Event.fireEvent(table, EventUtil.PG_DN_PR_EVENT);
        table.requestFocus();
    });
```

Note: the EventUtil.PG_DN_PR_EVENT emulate the PgDown key event.

Comment: Check the workaround described in https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8090721. It is for javafx 2 but might solve your problem.

Comment: @Selim it doesn't work on javafx 8, I got several compilation errors (starting from "Incompatible conditional operand types Node and ScrollBarSkin" at "n instanceof ScrollBarSkin"

Comment: Maybe a bit late for the party, but AFAIK (recently had the same problem) there is no "direct" way to do this, but you can use CSS-properties to achieve this.

Comment: @Samarek Thanks, it's not too late. I'll try your suggestion during next few days and I'll replay to your answer below.

Comment: @mauretto hey, just wondering if my suggestion helped ...

Comment: @Samarek I'll come back on this project this week, stay tuned!

Comment: @mauretto nice, I'll have my fingers crossed ;)

Comment: @Samarek ti worked, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell based on my own experiences, whether a `TableView` displays a `ScrollBar` or not depends on the buttons and arrows on the `ScrollBar`.

In my project I use this CSS code to hide both scrollbars

```
.table-view *.increment-button,
.table-view *.decrement-button,
.table-view *.increment-arrow,
.table-view *.decrement-arrow
{
    -fx-padding: 0;
    -fx-shape: "";
}
```

But this has sideeffects, since apparently the `TableMenuButton` uses the same padding the `TableMenuButton` disappears with a padding of 0, the only thing I keep seeing is one half of the "+" sign that is usually displayed on the button. So this is *a* way but not neccesarily *the* way.

Answer (score 6):

I think the best way to hide the scroll bars of a TableView is with CSS code.

This is the code for the vertical scroll bar.

```
.table-view *.scroll-bar:vertical *.increment-button,
.table-view *.scroll-bar:vertical *.decrement-button {
    -fx-background-color: null;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-padding: 0;
}

.table-view *.scroll-bar:vertical *.increment-arrow,
.table-view *.scroll-bar:vertical *.decrement-arrow {
    -fx-background-color: null;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-padding: 0;
    -fx-shape: null;
}
```

If you want to hide also the horizontal scroll bar, you have to add the same code but changing `*.scroll-bar:vertical` for `*.scroll-bar:horizontal`.

And if you want to scroll your table by code, I recommend to use the method [scrollTo](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#scrollTo%28int%29) that it's included in the TableView class.

Comment: Also works setting only the property `-fx-padding:0;`